# Laravel 5 mongodb driver and capped collection

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a capped collection within a migration using a 
[laravel-mongodb driver](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) . Seems like it's not a built-in feature, so I suppose I need to run a raw command. Can I do that with this library or I need to use native [php5 driver](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mongodb.php)?

Comment: check this - https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/800